I'm trying to teach myself to code,I wrote my first html and css code. It works fine on pc but on my phone it seems like the css is not working
It works fine on pc but on my phone it seems like the css part is not working. the page is showing all white whith no background and the text is not formatted.I'm trying to understand what errors I made? or is it possible that the error is not on the css part of the code?
thank you so much in advance for your answers.
I looked up here on stackoverflow too but I cant fix the problem. I already changed the width from px to %
I really tried but I cant solve it by myself.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Bar Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="Menu">
  <main>
    <h1>LA CASA DEL COCKTAIL</h1>
    <p>Cocktail Selection</p>
    <section>
      <h2>Vodka</h2>
      <article class="item">
      <p class="flavor">Cosmopolitan</p><p class="price">11.50</p>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
      <p class="flavor">Bloody Mary</p><p class="price">11.50</p>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
      <p class="flavor">Moscow Mule</p><p class="price">11.00</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section>
    <h2>Gin</h2>
    <article class="item">
    <p class="flavor">Negroni</p><p class="price">10.50</p>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
    <p class="flavor">French 75</p><p class="price">10.50</p>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
    <p class="flavor">Gimlet</p><p class="price">11.50</p>
    </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="*****">
    <p><a href="">click here for info</a>
    </p>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: shrikhand,impact;
  }
  p,h2 {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: impact;
    }
  body {
    background-image: url('https://dvclub.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Italian-Summer-Cocktails.jpg')
  }
 .Menu {
   background-image: url('https://dvclub.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Italian-Summer-Cocktails.jpg');
   width: 100%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding-left: 5%;
   padding-right: 5%;
   padding-top: 5%;
   max-width: 300px;
 }
  .flavor {
    font-family: cursive;
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .price {
    font-family: cursive;
    text-align: right;
    width: 25%;
  }
  .item p {
    display: inline-block;
  }


You can't just open the html in files. The WebView for the "Files" app doesn't load the file structure correctly even if you have the CSS file with correct file name relative path. Like mentioned above you should use remote debugging. This link is for Chrome on IOS but the methods are platform specific so for android and other browsers you'll need to do some research. Another option (not a good way to start IMO) is to deploy the host either using tools like nginx, or cloud servers like AWS/Heroku.

(There were communications in the staging ground clarifying that the files are sent over email and opened in files, but this post is approved (prematurely IMO) without following edit or closing.)
